# Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, firefox4

Firefox4 has a new feature  →　【Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs】

But it was also a trouble with me when I hope an alert dialog opened more than once.

Now, A new problem has appeared ...like below ↓

```
1) I call the alert dialog more than once , and check the  
  【Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs】
2) I click a download button , My web application is down....
```

(my button' event is below....  and because it hasn't into the action , so I'm just  write the client source....)

My Button Event

```
getDownloadFile:function(){
    $('xform').submit();
}
```

My Page Code

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <form id="xform" action="down.do" method="post" target="xfra">
    </form>
</div>
<iframe id="xfra" name="xfra" src="/?scid=dummy.htm" style="width:0px;height:0px;visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Hope anybody can help me ...thanks...

Comment: Can you reproduce this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xUvV5/) please? I have Firefox 5 and it won't do what you say.

Comment: Well, I guess that FF4 simply block JavaScript altogether when user choose to "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" - in such case, all you can do it ask your visitors to upgrade to Firefox 5 where this bad design is now fixed.

Comment: Oh, there is the same error as FF4 when I installed the FF5....orz..

Comment: Do you get the dialog when clicking twice the first button in the above jsFiddle link? Because I don't get such dialog here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I am guessing the `$` on your code means you are using jQuery (you should mention it in the tags if this is the case).</strike>

If you are not using jQuery, then I don't know much of the other frameworks' selectors. However, if it is jQuery, your selector is not correct, it should be:

```
$('#xform').submit();
```

not

```
$('xform').submit();
```

Since you are using PrototypeJS, the above is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm using the prototypejs .

Comment: @Okay, the above is null then. However I tried your test case and it [works just fine on FF 5](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/VWCp9/).

Comment: you may  create anohter button , and  try to call the [Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs] opened . when the checkbox is appeaed ,checked it !  then , you can redisappeared the probelm...

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a simple fix**:

```
function myAlertMsg() {
   alert("Whatever message you want");
   location.reload(); /*This prevents the browsers pop-up disabler*/
}
```